# Multi-item carousel in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Dears,

I'm trying to replicate a ondemand films/TV series platform, at the moment I would like to implement a different sections with multi-item carousel with two buttons (left - right).
What I would like to do is declare a function owing to move my carousel which is called separetely by each section, pressing the buttons (left - right).

here below you can find HTML code:

```html
    <div class="homeContainer">
      <!-- Section 1 -->
      <div class="sezione">
        <h2>Titolo della sezione</h2>
        <div class="sliderContainer" #slider>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right fa-xl" id="right"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left fa-xl" id="left"></i>
          <div class="slider" [style.transform]="'translateX('+ xMovement + 'px)'">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="assets/img/CardImage_300X200.png" alt="">
              <div>
                <h3>Titolo del film</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo harum magni quas pariatur dicta fugit
                  voluptatem aspernatur officia maxime repellat! Laboriosam, ratione? Autem eos aliquid soluta blanditiis
                  molestiae. Illum, assumenda?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <img src="assets/img/CardImage_300X200.png" alt="">
              <div>
                <h3>Titolo del film</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo harum magni quas pariatur dicta fugit
                  voluptatem aspernatur officia maxime repellat! Laboriosam, ratione? Autem eos aliquid soluta blanditiis
                  molestiae. Illum, assumenda?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="card">
              <img src="assets/img/CardImage_300X200.png" alt="">
              <div>
                <h3>Titolo del film</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo harum magni quas pariatur dicta fugit
                  voluptatem aspernatur officia maxime repellat! Laboriosam, ratione? Autem eos aliquid soluta blanditiis
                  molestiae. Illum, assumenda?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="card">
              <img src="assets/img/CardImage_300X200.png" alt="">
              <div>
                <h3>Titolo del film</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo harum magni quas pariatur dicta fugit
                  voluptatem aspernatur officia maxime repellat! Laboriosam, ratione? Autem eos aliquid soluta blanditiis
                  molestiae. Illum, assumenda?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="card">
              <img src="assets/img/CardImage_300X200.png" alt="">
              <div>
                <h3>Titolo del film</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo harum magni quas pariatur dicta fugit
                  voluptatem aspernatur officia maxime repellat! Laboriosam, ratione? Autem eos aliquid soluta blanditiis
                  molestiae. Illum, assumenda?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Section 2 -->
      <div class="sezione">
        <h2>Titolo della sezione</h2>
        <div class="sliderContainer" #slider>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right fa-xl" id="right"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left fa-xl" id="left"></i>
          <div class="slider" [style.transform]="'translateX('+ xMovement + 'px)'">
            <div class="card" #card>
              <img src="assets/img/CardImage_300X200.png" alt="">
              <div>
                <h3>Titolo del film</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo harum magni quas pariatur dicta fugit
                  voluptatem aspernatur officia maxime repellat! Laboriosam, ratione? Autem eos aliquid soluta blanditiis
                  molestiae. Illum, assumenda?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card">
              <img src="assets/img/CardImage_300X200.png" alt="">
              <div>
                <h3>Titolo del film</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo harum magni quas pariatur dicta fugit
                  voluptatem aspernatur officia maxime repellat! Laboriosam, ratione? Autem eos aliquid soluta blanditiis
                  molestiae. Illum, assumenda?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="card">
              <img src="assets/img/CardImage_300X200.png" alt="">
              <div>
                <h3>Titolo del film</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo harum magni quas pariatur dicta fugit
                  voluptatem aspernatur officia maxime repellat! Laboriosam, ratione? Autem eos aliquid soluta blanditiis
                  molestiae. Illum, assumenda?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="card">
              <img src="assets/img/CardImage_300X200.png" alt="">
              <div>
                <h3>Titolo del film</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo harum magni quas pariatur dicta fugit
                  voluptatem aspernatur officia maxime repellat! Laboriosam, ratione? Autem eos aliquid soluta blanditiis
                  molestiae. Illum, assumenda?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="card">
              <img src="assets/img/CardImage_300X200.png" alt="">
              <div>
                <h3>Titolo del film</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo harum magni quas pariatur dicta fugit
                  voluptatem aspernatur officia maxime repellat! Laboriosam, ratione? Autem eos aliquid soluta blanditiis
                  molestiae. Illum, assumenda?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="card" #card>
              <img src="assets/img/CardImage_300X200.png" alt="">
              <div>
                <h3>Titolo del film</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo harum magni quas pariatur dicta fugit
                  voluptatem aspernatur officia maxime repellat! Laboriosam, ratione? Autem eos aliquid soluta blanditiis
                  molestiae. Illum, assumenda?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Based on the HTML code below, I tried to implement this part of TS code, but I am not able to find a solution due to call a movement method separately for each carousel

Here below TS code:

```
// ------------- ngOnInit -------------
      ngOnInit() {
        this.sliderContiner = document.querySelectorAll('.sliderContainer');
        console.log(this.sliderContiner);
        this.sliderContiner.forEach((element: any) => {
          this.sliderMovement(element);
        });
      }
// -------------------------------------
  sliderMovement(element: any) {
    console.log(element.childNodes);
    const rightButton = element.childNodes[0];
    const leftButton = element.childNodes[1];
    const slider = element.childNodes[2];
    console.log(rightButton);
    console.log(leftButton);
    console.log(slider);
    let counter: number;
  }
```

Is there anyone that could be help me to find out a solution about to add an event click listener on mi right and left button?

Comment: Pardon, but this does look like you'd like somebody to write the function for you, which is not the intention of the site. You should try it yourself and if you run into a problem, come back here and ask a question about your problem, ideally with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Add some buttons and add a click event on it. `<button (click)="...">left-arrow</button>` You can figure out the rest by using angular documentation